# How to transfer polyline shapefile into raster data using Python

Tags: python, gis, gdal, shapely, fiona

Here is my question. I have a bunch of polyline shows like:

http://i4.tietuku.com/bc378d1cd2c24142.png

I want to generater raster data based on the polyline which contain the length of the line in one grid.

For example:

1. original data
   http://i4.tietuku.com/8b8768aac183cfe6.png
2. Aim

http://i4.tietuku.com/a09ba42a122f561a.png

===== Add ====

Found the answer using ArcGIS from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151365/converting-polylines-to-raster-assigning-value-of-total-length-of-lines-within)

using R from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119993/convert-line-shapefile-to-raster-value-total-length-of-lines-within-cell)

My target is convert the polyline into raster using Python
with some open-source modules(gdal, fiona, etc)

Comment: This is best directed here http://gis.stackexchange.com/ but in any event a featureclass can only contain one geometry type so if you have points, polylines and polygons, you will have to treat them separately.  In your example, you show a closed-loop polyline instead of a polygon.  It will not produce the enclosed area that you desire unless you convert it to a polygon first.  You should specify what software you have access to as well, particularly if this is GIS related

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to using python with some module to get the work done. The example I showed may be confusing. For now, I want to   transfer the polyline( which represent the road networks)  into the raster data

Comment: For now, I can use [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) to get the interaction of the road and my made-up grid. But the loop all over the space cost so much time. So, I'm working on generate the grid along the road（I  have already used K-d tree algorithm to locate the start grid and end grid of one polyline）

Comment: Your options are `gdal.RasterizeLayers` or `rasterio.features.rasterize`. Both work really well for rasterizing vector data.